# Emacs "No route to host" :name "elpa.gnu.org"

Tags: emacs, startup, elpa

I just started getting this when I start up my Emacs (at command line with `emacs --debug-init`):

```
Lisp error: (file-error "make client process failed" "No route to host" :name "elpa.gnu.org" :buffer #<killed buffer> :host "elpa.gnu.org" :service 80 :nowait nil :tls-parameters nil)
  signal(file-error ("make client process failed" "No route to host" :name "elpa.gnu.org" :buffer #<killed buffer> :host "elpa.gnu.org" :service 80 :nowait nil :tls-parameters nil))
  package--download-one-archive(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") "archive-contents" nil)
```

A restart with `emacs --insecure` and just `emacs` however seems to work. BTW, I've got everything setting up with `use-package` with `:ensure t` set. The good restarts, however, produce this in `*Messages*` when I do a `M-x list-packages` but then skip over and finish just fine:

```
error in process sentinel: Error retrieving: http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/archive-contents (error connection-failed "failed with code 113
" :host "elpa.gnu.org" :service 80)
```

I googled and saw various init setup tinkering solutions ... which I don't believe apply to this particular issue. I'm guessing there's something wrong "out there", not on my machine. Any ideas/suggestions? I'm on latest Ubuntu and Emacs 26.2.

Comment: they appear to be moving servers -- https://quitter.im/fsfstatus

Comment: I thought it was something like that. Seems to work fine now. Should I delete this post or is it of value as such?

Comment: The first things you do in such cases is use `dig elpa.gnu.org` and see if you can get an IP address; then ping the ip address, ping the host, traceroute the host. If all of that fails (as it probably would in this case), emacs has no hope of connecting: the problem is indeed "out there".